# Could not find generator user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby version 2.0.0 and rails version 4.0.0

whenever i do

```
rails g model user email:string password_hash:string password_salt:string
```

I get error i;e

```
Could not find generator user.
```

Comment: `rails g model User ...`

Comment: Well, my fault, just checked and it generates user model with `user`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your model should be singular or first alphabet capitaql

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a capital to the first letter of your model like:

> rails g model User email:string password_hash:string password_salt:string

Comment: I think that's not a solution.

Comment: Does it still not working with a capital ?
This syntax is on every tutorial you'll read. It's a naming convention.